# multiple sAjaxDataProp: items in 1 table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable, datatables

I'm making an table with the JavaScript for DataTables.

I've got it working when I only have to use 1 JSON item data from the controller.

when I'm using multiple JSON items in 1 table I don't know how to access it.

in my controller:

```
$output = array("sEcho" => $sEcho,
            "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
            "ridedata" =>$data,
            "assigneduserdata1" =>$assignedUsers1Filtered,
            "assigneduserdata2" =>$assignedUsers2Filtered);
    echo json_encode($output);
```

the output:

```
{"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":13,"iTotalDisplayRecords":13,"ridedata":[{"DeviceID":"1","Vehicle":"20",...}]
,"assigneduserdata1":{"username":"harry","Vehicle":"20",...}
,"assigneduserdata2":{"username":"henk","Vehicle":"20",...}}
```

I've tested my JSON its a valid output(as you get I've only put the data relevant for this here)

now my ride has users assigned which I would like to show their username and also the device that's coupled to this ride.

in my JavaScript I am trying to use:

```
 "sAjaxSource": getDataRequestURL(),
"sAjaxDataProp": "assigneduserdata1","assigneduserdata2","ridedata",
```

I've also tried :

```
 "sAjaxSource": getDataRequestURL(),
"sAjaxDataProp": "assigneduserdata1",
"sAjaxDataProp": "assigneduserdata2",
"sAjaxDataProp": "ridedata",
```

when ever I try to use source.Vehicle I get the vehicle id just fine also I do get the deviceid when using source.DeviceID but I can't access what user is linked to it(like getting the username)

when I turn my sajaxdataprop like :

```
"sAjaxDataProp": "ridedata",
"sAjaxDataProp": "assigneduserdata1",
"sAjaxDataProp": "assigneduserdata2",
```

I can get my username(from assignedusersdata2) and my vehicle id but I can't get my deviceid.

now my question is how could I access
both the username and the deviceid.(the username of both of the assignedusers)

since I would need them both

like multiple colums.(username,vehicleid,deviceid)
right now I get as I said earlier :
(undifiend,vehicleid,deviceid)
or something like:
(username,vehicleid,undifiend)

My question is what could I do to change this so I could access both of the data?
Is this a JSON problem?
Should I change something in my controller or should I change something in my JSON?